# Google script, MailApp не отправляет письмо

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Пытаюсь запустить скрипт отправки письма из таблицы:

```
function myMail() {
  MailApp.sendEmail("почта адресата", "тема",
  "тело письма")
}
```

Все разрешения даны, консоль пишет, что скрипт выполнен, но письмо не приходит - ни на почту gmail, ни на любую другую. Пробовал запустить и из редактора скриптов, и из таблицы, каждый раз якобы выполняется, но результата нет. Так же пробовал скопировать готовые таблицы со скриптом из роликов с ютуба, так же не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Что вы хотите выслать?
Имеется какой код который высылает ваши ячейки.

```
var ID = "1sBtjJ9x4IKwb9GKu3x3DwoNWTxPej7HJW"; //ваш speadsheet id
var EMAIL = "Test@gmail.com"; //на какой майл отправить email 
var RANGE = "Warranty_2021!B121:N129"; // какие ячейки, data range to send
var text = "Тест"; // тема subject


function sendData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
  var data = spreadsheet.getRangeByName(RANGE).getValues();
  var message = {};
  { //condition
  message.subject = "[La Test] " + text;
  message.to = EMAIL;
  message.htmlBody = dataToHtmlTable_(data) +
    "<br><br>[IT care you ;)]";
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  }
  let quota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  console.log(quota)
}
```